# Using self inside objective c method

Tags: ios, objective-c, linked-list, self

I was trying to write code for LinkedList in Objective C and I stumble upon one of the implementation of method.

```
- (void)removeDuplicates
{
FALinkedList *head = self; //Self is FALinkedList object inherited from NSObject.
if (!head || !head.next) return;

FALinkedList *pre = nil;
NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
while (head) {
    if (![dict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",head.data]]) {
        [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
                 forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",head.data]];
        pre = head;
    } else {
        pre.next = head.next;
    }
    head = head.next;
}
}
```

This method is working but I am not sure if I can directly assign self to temporary object inside method.

Any suggestion / comments / pointers towards resources will be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This method is working but I am not sure if I can directly assign self to temporary object inside method.

Yes, `self` is simply a pointer to the object executing the method. You can assign `self` to a local variable without causing any problem.

Comment: Great, Thanks for prompt answer.